# IEEEtran appendix in new page with new title as if it was a new document

Tags: sectioning, titles, appendices, titling, titleps

How to make `\appendix` or the `\section`s after `\appendices` appear in new pages and with the title style as the main title in an IEEEtran document class?

The following images show an example of what it is desired (probably without the authors everytime).

[image: Desired]

Answer (score 1):

the class doesn't try too hard to clear `\maketitle` if it is executed in a group the definition is preserved:

[image]

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}

\title{My Custom Title}
\author{Author 1,
Author 2}
\makeatletter
\begin{document}

{\maketitle}


\clearpage


\title{My New Title}
{\maketitle}

bbb
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't think this will allow me to cross reference, however is the desired output. Although, the ability to cross reference is a requirement. Do you think is there a way to do it?

Comment: @Hans latex cross references are built around referencable numbers, what do you want `\ref{zzz]` to produce? You can't normally reference a title, that said if you go `\makeatletter\def\@currentlabel{my title}\lable{zzz}` then `\ref{zzz}` will make `my title`.

Comment: I understand what you say, however when doing "\appendices \section{sec} \label{app:sec}" I can get a reference to the appendix, please note that my question is directed towards making the appendix title appear exactly the same as the main title. Note also that in my example images, the appendices have "numbers" which are A and B, these are the references. I really appreciate your answer as I've used in a document already, however the requirement is different.

Comment: David, you think it is possible to make something like `\title{\section{My New Title}}` while preserving the title style?

Comment: @Hans anything is possible but `\title{\section{My New Title}}` is so obviously incorrect document structure that I wouldn't even want to think about it,  what would a section heading in a title supposed to _mean_ ?

Comment: Well, that would be the desired output, in IEEEtran, when placing `\appendices`, then every `\section{}` is displayed as "Appendix A", "Appendix B", etc. I would like to have this with the `\title` style, and this could be properly referenced with `\ref` as the Appendices can be referenced.

Comment: Hope I'm not bothering you too much, today I had some time, you'll see I am not a TeX expert, I did my best and obtained the desired result in not a very nice way. I shall say, it is not important the author and annotations appear in the appendices. Anyway, I wanted you to have a loook at my answer, hoping maybe you get what I was trying to achieve and provide your expert opinion and corrections.

Answer (score 1):

A partial (yet ugly) solution is the following:

### MWE:

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{My Document}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\lipsum[0-4]
{\Huge Reference to section \ref{sec:mTS} and appendix \ref{app:t2}}
\section{My Test Section}
\label{sec:mTS}
\lipsum[5-7]

{\Huge Reference to appendix \ref{app:t3}}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\section{\@startsection{section}{1}{\z@}{1.5ex plus 1.5ex minus 0.5ex}%
{0.7ex plus 1ex minus 0ex}{\vskip 1.3em\Huge\centering}}
\makeatother

\appendices
\twocolumn[\section{Test 1\vspace{1.3\baselineskip}}\label{app:t1}]
\lipsum[1-2]
\subsection{Test appendix section here.}
\label{app:t3}
\lipsum[3-7]
\twocolumn[\section{Test 2\vspace{1.3\baselineskip}}\label{app:t2}]
\lipsum[1-2]
\subsection{Another test section in here}
\label{app:t4}
\lipsum[3-7]
\end{document}
```

The solution is ugly because the appendices titles need to be typed like `\twocolumn[\section{Appendix Title Here\vspace{1.3\baselineskip}}\label{AppendixLabelHere}]`, *autem* this generates the desired output, and one can reference it, as shown in the following pictures (reference were printed Huge, in order for the reader to see them without too much effort).

[image: Solution Obtained]

Any corrections are very appreciated.